# How to delete "Not you or want to join..for a different person"?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contribution-page

I am a newbie to CiviCRM but have just managed to upgrade civicrm wordpress from 4.5.8 to 4.6.2.

On my membership contribution page, there is now the following entry at the beginning of the text "Welcome Mr. XXX. (Not Mr. XXX, or want to do this for a different person?).  This text wasn't there before. After clicking on the link, the user then gets taken to another page where  they can enter details for the other person.  After entering a few details, other members personal details including names, phone numbers, addresses etc begin to emerge which is not good from a security point of view.

How do I turn off the facility to accept payment for a different person
please?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you see when you have "other members personal details" that emerge is either because they are stored by your browser (so civicrm isn't involved, it's a browser feature) or because you are logged in as a user that has the right to see other members.

Try doing it without being logged in (eg. using the anonymous mode of your browser), you will see that civicrm doesn't show private information to anonymous visitors

Comment: Many thanks Xavier for your answer.  I set up an anonymous user and logged in using his details and the information I then saw was different to me logging in as administrator.  So you were correct and the private information didn't show up.

Comment: Sorry but I thought I had already done that.  Your answer has now been accepted.  Thanks for your help.